# Scale_size and scale_alpha_manual based on group name

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame that looks like this.

```
time <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2)
category <- c("cat1","cat2","cat3","cat1","cat2","cat3","cat1","cat2","cat3")
value <- c(0.5,0.6,0.7,1.5,1.6,1.7,2.5,2.6,2.7)

test <- data.frame(time, category, value)
```

[image]

I want to change the alpha - **transparency** and the **size** manually for each category. Since I can not use values but only the name of the category, how could I proceed?

I want something like

```
scale_alpha_discrete(values=c("cat1"=0.4, "cat2"=0.5,"cat3"=0.6))
```

but this does not work of course

Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't just using `scale_alpha_manual()` instead of the discrete version work exactly as you intend?

Comment: You are right  @teunbrand that was stupid of me. Please feel free to update the comment to answer and I ll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the comment of teunbrand. The code could be like this.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x = time, y = value, colour=category, alpha=category)) +
  geom_line(size=2) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue","red","yellow"))+
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.1, 0.5, .6))
```

[image]